# Execute docker-compose from inside ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have problem executing `docker-compose` which is called from inside ansible playbook, I have try few way but all give me an error:

**1.**

```
docker_service:
        project_src: /test/docker/   
        command: docker-compose -f {{ name }}_compose.yml  up -d
```

**2.**

```
docker_service:
        project_src: /test/docker/
        files:
            src: "{{ name }}_compose.yml"
        state: present
```

**Errors are various:**

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to import docker or docker-py - No module named 'requests'. Try `pip install docker` or `pip install docker-py` (Python 2.6)"}

FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (docker_service) module: command Supported parameters include: api_version, build, cacert_path, cert_path, debug, definition, dependencies, docker_host, files, hostname_check, key_path, nocache, project_name, project_src, pull, recreate, remove_images, remove_orphans, remove_volumes, restarted, scale, services, ssl_version, state, stopped, timeout, tls, tls_hostname, tls_verify"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The task below should start up your compose file.

```
- name: Deploy docker compose
  docker_compose:
    project_src: /test/docker/
    files:
      - "./{{ name }}_compose.yml"
    state: present
```

It looks like you don't have the `docker` python module installed which is required to use the docker modules in Ansible.  You can install that using pip in the task below.

```
- name: Ensure docker python module is present
  pip:
    name: docker[tls]
```

You may also need to install pip which will vary depending on your OS and package manager

**Note:** Ansible has changed the name of the `docker_service` module to `docker_compose` starting in version 2.8